# synchronization between videos to CSV files

Tags: sql, csv, video, synchronization

i'm looking for a technology that provides me synchronization of videos and CSV files. does anyone know about something?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific?
In most cases videos and csv are files. Of course you can store files in many types of database you can also check if files in DB and files on file system are identical and relace them.